# How to number tables and figures according to sections and subsections independently?

Tags: sectioning, floats, numbering

I am writing a document that does not required much formalisms, but I want to implement the following numbering system:

```
1 Section
Table 1: Caption
Figure 1: Caption
1.1 Subsection
Table 1.1: Caption
Figure 1.1: Caption
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: How should a second figure in "Section 1" be numbered? How a second figure in "Subsection 1.1"?

Comment: Good spotted. It would only work with one figure and one table per subsection.

Comment: Does your comment mean that the question is moot (in which case it will likely be closed)? If not, I suggest you elaborate on your (rather unusual) numbering scheme, specifying how floats in a second section or in a second subsection within the first section should be numbered.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, my initial idea was about the problem restrained to one figure/one table per subsection. A very particular case.
If it happens that the question is narrowed and moot, how could I close it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appends `b`, `c` .. if there is more than one float in each section.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{table}{subsection}
\@addtoreset{figure}{subsection}
\@addtoreset{table}{section}
\@addtoreset{figure}{section}


\renewcommand\thefigure{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}=0 \thesection\else\thesubsection\fi\ifnum\value{figure}>1 \alph{figure}\fi}
\renewcommand\thetable{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}=0 \thesection\else\thesubsection\fi\ifnum\value{table}>1 \alph{table}\fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\section{zzz}

a
\begin{table}[!htp]TTTT\caption{tt}\end{table}

b
\begin{figure}[!htp]FFF\caption{ff}\end{figure}


\subsection{www}


a
\begin{table}[!htp]TTTT\caption{tt tt}\end{table}

b
\begin{figure}[!htp]FFF\caption{ff ff}\end{figure}

aa
\begin{table}[!htp]TTTT\caption{tt tt tt}\end{table}

bb
\begin{figure}[!htp]FFF\caption{ff ff ff}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```